# Slot machine animation using UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, contentoffset

I need to implement slot-machine animation according to provided design and timings.

It should perform infinite scroll, until some event will be triggered. After that animation, it should slow down and stop on defined position

For this task I have used next solution:

- `UITableView` with `fixed-height` cell. It is the same cell with the only difference - icon or text (depends on `indexPath.row`)
- `Scroll` is only down-to-up that's why I'm using last cell as start point in `resetScrollPosition` method
- If first element reached, scroll position resets to start point
- Animation performed as `contentOffset` change with linear option. In completion block, if animation is still needed, it's called again. If don't needed - slowing animation with `easeOut` option started

```swift
var isRolling: Bool = false

func startScroll() {
    isRolling = true

    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.05,
        delay: 0,
        options: .curveLinear,
        animations: {
            self.tableView.contentOffset.y -= self.rowHeight
    },
        completion: { _ in
            if self.isRolling {
                self.startScroll()
            } else {
                self.resetScrollPosition

                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: 0.7,
                    delay: 0,
                    options: .curveEaseOut,
                    animations: {
                         self.tableView.contentOffset.y -= 8 * self.rowHeight
                },
                    completion: nil
                )
            }
    })
}

private func resetScrollPosition() {
    tableView.reloadData()

    tableView.contentOffset.y = startOffset
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func stopScroll() {
    isRolling = false
}
```

**The problems:**

1. After calling `resetScrollPosition`, in animations completion block, tableviews `contentOffset.y` value is updated but `tableView` stays on the same position. I have tried to change direct `contentOffset` changing to `setContentOffset`, `scrollToRow`, `scrollToRect`, wrap it in main queue - no changes
2. Slowing animation should scroll 8 items. It's performed but first 6 items aren't visible during animation, only the last two.
   Check the issue gif (jump 2 -> 11 is ok): [image: slot animation issue]

Comment: I would remove the tableview and just use a scroll view directly. That way you have more control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced `UITableView` with `UIScrollView`

Uploaded code to gist - https://gist.github.com/OlesenkoViktor/76845c5448b421ead0a2303af2b1161d

Thanks @Paulw11 for [his idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423280/slot-machine-animation-using-uitableview#comment105046553_59423280)